# Change profile picture using angular js ng-click

Tags: angularjs

I'm still newbie with angular js
I get difficulties to change profile picture

```
<img src="images/avatar.jpg" ng-click="changeProfilePicture()">
```

How can I change my profile picture using ng-click,
all i know is when we click then there will be a pop up, then we choose our image, then the image will be converted to base 64 string to be saved in database, then the base 64 string will be converted to image again, then the profile picture will be changed.
How to do that?

Comment: this question is too much broad. there are plenty of angular directive for file upload. first serach try some thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my projects I use [ng-file-upload](https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload) directive for uploading images to a web server. See docs and demo, may be it will help you.